# Efficient way to get child entity/keys given a parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I wanted to ask if there is a direct and efficient way to get the
child of a parent entity.

I am modelling a follower/ following relationship(like twitter). So I
have a user model and a message model.
I have a Follower and Following model which have a user model as a parent.

So whenever a user writes a message(or say tweet), all his followers
should be able to get that.
In this case I need to figure out who are the followers of the
user(who sends a message).

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you mean to call the models `Followed` and `Following`? Also, this is probably a bad example for the use of ancestry, since the parent and child kinds have a many-to-many relationship (e.g., deleting a `followed` doesn't result in its `following` being deleted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ancestor queries. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_ancestor
Or
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor

Comment: Thanks Guido... I was actually using db and not ndb. Need to go through the ndb docs. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another method of finding the children of an entity is to instantiate a `ndb.Query` object, passing `ancestor` to its constructor:

```
joe = Followed.get_by_id('joe')

query = ndb.Query(ancestor = joe.key)

followers = query.fetch()
```

This also provides a more general way to find the children of an entity without requiring their `Kind` to be known in advance.